# Convert "Image byte array" into "Image object" in node.js

Tags: node.js, opencv

I have byte array of image and I want to convert it into image object using `opencv` in `node.js`.

I am looking for some function in `node.js` similar to [DecodeImageMem()](https://github.com/lazywei/go-opencv/blob/master/opencv/goimage.go#L11), this is provided in `golang binding` of `openCV`, It can be used in this way.

```
  decodedImage:=opencv.DecodeImageMem(data)   //data is byte array.
```

So, someone please tell me how can I convert byte array of image into `image object`, so that I can find it's dimensions ?

Or, you guys can suggest me some other library in `node.js` so that I can find dimensions of a given byte array.

Comment: You can obtain the image dimensions of image only if you have used `imencode` to generate the byte array. If the byte array is generated using `img.data`, then you may not recover width/height of the image as the image has been serialized to a linear array of RGB values and you need to explicitly pass width, height of the image. But in case of `imencode`, you can use `imdecode` to re-generate the image object.

Comment: Actually My Image is taken from **S3** storage, and This is byte array not the one which is generated by `img.data`, But the functions you are suggesting, are those functions available for node.js and will it work in my case, and including `dimensions` I also want to find `img.data` also of that byte array. So please suggest me something in node.js which can find both of those values.

Comment: If you are using OpenCV API in node js, then there must be some `imdecode()` method in some module.

Comment: @ZdaR there is no `imdecode()` function of `opencv`  wrapper in `node.js`